# Russell's Response to Zeno's Paradox

Tags: zeno-of-elea

I understand that Bertrand Russell, in repsonse to Zeno's Paradox, uses his concept of motion: an object being at a different time at different places, instead of the "from-to" notion of motion.

I also understand that this concept solves Zeno's Paradox of the arrow, as his concept aptly describes the motion of the arrow; however, his concept of motion does not aptly resolve Zeno's Paradox when told as the "dichotomy" and the "race". 
However, I don't understand the following quote:

> But it is  not essential to the existence of a collection, or even to
>   knowledge  and reasoning concerning it, that we should be able to pass
>   its  terms in review one by one.

Can someone explain why this addition to his notion of motion not fully account for the "race" and the "dichotomy"?

Comment: Dear Curious_Mind- A segment is not a distance; Is that solved? CMS

Comment: I'm confused with what you are trying to imply. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: By saying that an arrow travels halfway, the so-called paradox converts a distance into a segment. Halfway is not a distance traveled, it is a portion of the distance measured as a fraction. Reducing the halfway 'segment' until it disappears has nothing to do with distance. It is the wrong category of measurement to use when suggesting that motion is impossible. Cheers CMS

Comment: Be(r)trand who ?

Comment: See [Zeno’s Paradoxes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/) for a review of the everlasting discussions about it.

Comment: According to whom does his concept of motion "solves Zeno's Paradox of the arrow", but "does not aptly resolve Zeno's Paradox when told as the "dichotomy" and the "race""? Since you are asking I assume you read it in a commentary somewhere. Since Russell objects to counting milestones one by one before passing a collection of them is allowed this should work for dichotomy as well. The problem with Russell's "solution" is that his concept of motion is a concept of a collection of rests, and not of motion at all.

Comment: It seems to me that whether or not one accepts Russell's solution is likely to depend on whether one is thinking in terms of McTaggar's [A theory or B theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#McTArg)--the B theory puts time on essentially the same footing as a geometrical dimension, so asking how a moving object can reach a finish line is similar to asking how the line y=2x in a 2D x-y coordinate system can "reach" the point (x=1, y=2) if it has to travel through the infinite series of intermediate points like (x=1/2, y=1) and (x=3/4, y=3/2) and (x=7/8, y=7/4) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Bertrand Russell wasn't very keen on ancient philosophy and I doubt he took Aristotle's solution to Zeno's question on what constitutes motion.

Bertrands assertion is at odds with Aristotle - for he says that if the collection is infinite, then they can be passed if they are potential but not if they are actual. I would suggest that Russell was rekying upon the theory of inginite series.

This is most common solution to Zeno's question, that is to use infinite series. Now, although there was no such thing as infinite series in Aristotle's time, it is clear from his discussion that they were understood qualitatively, if not formally, and he says that they are an 'adequate' answer but not the true answer.

For the latter, he uses his theory of potentiality and actuality and says that motion is an alternation of potential motion with actual motion; potential motion is becoming and changeful but not actual; whilst actual motion is not in fact motion, it is not changeful, but rest.

Interestingly, just like Parmenides he says that which is actual does not move. As Zeno was supporting Parmenides, in some sense he is verifying both Zeno & Parmenides.

It's also worth noting that Hegel supported Aristotle. He said that the reason why something moved is because it is both here and there - a sort of super-position.

Moreover, it should be noted the close analogy between Aristotles conception of motion and quantum evolution. In quantum mechanics, the quantum potential evolves and is not real whilst the the quantum reduction does not change but is real. Notice that the quantum potential is both here and there - just as Hegel suggested.

Answer (score -2):

Zeno's paradox should be understood as an inadvertent reductio ad absurdum.

That is, the paradox shows that if moving from A to B required, as is implicitly assumed in the paradox, that we should be able to "*pass its term in review one by one*", that is, that we should be able to review one by one all successive locations in an *uncountable continuum* of locations, then moving would indeed be impossible. Yet, as the paradox itself in fact assumes explicitly this time, and more importantly as we can all check for ourselves, moving is not only possible but happens and happens all the time. Therefore, the paradox's implicit assumption is falsified.

Zeno's argument only works as a paradox because the crucial assumption, i.e. that counting an uncountable set is somehow a necessary pre-condition for moving, is not articulated. Thus, the only assumption which is falsifiable doesn't appear and isn't so easy to uncover. There is nothing in evidence which is falsifiable.

Comment: That's not true. 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 ... (in one version) or 1/2, 3/4, 7/18, 15/16, ... (in another) are countably infinite sets.

Comment: However there is an uncountable set of positions through which the arrow must pass on its journey, being the irrational number in the range zero to (length of journey), so there is still an argument to be made.  Whether it’s any more persuasive than for a countable set is another matter.

Comment: @user4894 Read again. I said "*uncountable continuum of locations*".

Comment: Zeno's argument doesn't seem to required that. Suppose the line is made up of only rational points. The argument still works. Suppose it only contains the dyadic rationals, the ones of the form n/2^m. The argument still works.

Comment: user4894 "**Countably**" infinite sets? Words are really cheap. So, go on, count 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 till the end and come back when you're done.

Comment: @Speakpigeon So you are using the word uncountable to mean ... what, exactly, since you apparently reject the standard mathematical usage?

Comment: @user4894 I mean what everybody does. Countable means that it can be counted. Mathematicians can invent their own private language but we are speaking English here.

Comment: @Speakpigeon Then what exactly do you mean by uncountable in the context of the real number line?

Comment: @user4894 Where is the problem? Everybody knows what "uncountable" means in English. The reals are certainly uncountable in this sens, Can you count the reals? No, you cannot. This irrespective of what mathematicians may mean by "uncountable". Mathematicians have their private language and this is fine, but don't expect people speaking English to stop speaking English to speak that lingo instead. .

Comment: @Speakpigeon LOL

Comment: Not sure why you're bringing up the reals since mathematicians already agree with "ordinary English" that the set of all real numbers is uncountable, though they'd say the non-continuous series 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ... is countable. And in any case you haven't explained why this quibble about the "ordinary English" meaning of "countable" is relevant to Zeno's paradox (which doesn't directly mention 'counting' anything) or Russell's statement (which doesn't use the word 'count' either, though 'pass its terms in review one by one' presumably refers to the mathematician's notion of countability).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Have you read the comments? It's not me bringing up the reals. The series 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 etc. is also not countable. "*though 'pass its terms in review one by one' presumably refers to the mathematician's notion of countability).*" Not quite but this muddy the water. Zeno requires that there is a finite number of steps when moving, and so countable in the ordinary sense, and mathematicians confuse the debate by insisting that some infinite sets are "countable" when in fact they are not.

Comment: The reals were brought up with the comment "what exactly do you mean by uncountable in the context of the real number line?", I don't think that comment was suggesting the real numbers were countable under the mathematician's definition. As for Zeno, I think his objections was primarily about it taking an infinite *time* to get somewhere if there were an infinite series of steps from here to there, but I suppose this is equivalent to requiring a finite number of steps if you add the implicit (wrong) assumption that infinite steps each taking finite time must add up to infinite time.

Answer (score -3):

solution is
infinite series is independently valid
motion of arrow is independently valid
therefore the dependency has to be met
ie the infinite series has to be registered in real time as arrow moves
paradox solved since contravention of laws of nature (relativity)
ie infinite speed of register invalid

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: first consider the infinite series applied to the points A B the sequence of 1/2 points now 2 ways first to register these 1/2 points casually and anytime at irregular times second to register positions in real time for a fixed velocity the first of course is never completed and no particular problem the second is quickly impossible to realize since it  calls for speeds of registration which contravene laws of nature according to relativity it is this second way which applies to zeno otherwise the infinite series is quite unrelated to the movement between a and b